# ¿Como aplicarle un Restrict a una relacion entre 2 entidades? (Symfony 6)

Tags: php, symfony

Tengo una relación entre 2 entidades (cargo y empleado) y quiero saber si hay una forma de agregarle un Restrict al momento de eliminar y personalizar el mensaje de error.

**RELACION:** Empleado y Cargo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CODIGO (Entidad Empleado):** Antes estaba con un SetNull

```
#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Cargo::class, inversedBy: 'empleados')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "cargo_id", referencedColumnName:"id", onDelete: "")]
private $cargo;
```

> GRACIAS.

Comment: no basta con colocar un error en el delete de PK de la entidad de la relacion???

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, aplicas "RESTRICT" a tu relación. Esto generará una exception de tipo `Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConstraintViolationException` que deberás controlar en tu servicio o controller, y te dará chance a personalizar el mensaje de error

```
#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Cargo::class, inversedBy: 'empleados')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "cargo_id", referencedColumnName:"id", onDelete: "RESTRICT")]
private $cargo;
```

Controller:

```
public function eliminarController(Request $request, ManagerRegistry $manager, LoggerInterface $logger): Response
    try{
        $id=$request->get('id', 0);
        
        $em=$manager->getManager();
        
        $cargo=$em->getRepository(Cargo::class)->find($id);
        if(is_null($cargo){
            throw new \Exception("No se pudo obtener el registro seleccionado", 404);
        }
        
        $em->remove($cargo);
        $em->flush();
    }catch(Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConstraintViolationException $cvExc){
        $loggerService->error($cvExc->getMessage());
        throw new \Exception("no es posible eliminar el registro. Está en uso en algún empleado.", 500);
    }
    catch(\Exception $exc){     
        if($exc->getCode()===404){
            throw $this->createNotFoundException($exc->getMessage());
        }
        
        // en cualquier otro caso, loggear el error original y lanzar uno con un mensaje mas personalizado
        $loggerService->error($exc->getMessage());
        throw new \Exception("Ocurrió un error inesperado. Consulte con soporte para su solución."; 
    }
    
    return new Response("Registro eliminado correctamente o lo que desees hacer");
}
```